# ElasticSearch is not showing the duplicate value within a array field

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, opensearch

I have an index let's call it "INDEX-01"

```
    INDEX-01
     "IPS":[
        "1.2.3.4",
        "192.16.2.4",
        "192.16.2.3",
        "192.16.2.4"
    ]
```

there is a duplicate IP entry

Here is the mapping of the field:

```
            "IPS": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            }
```

I am running a query to simply return the array using the script_field but the output does not show the duplicate value, here is the query

```
"output" : 
            [
              "1.2.3.4",
              "192.16.2.3",
              "192.16.2.4",
              null
            ]
```

the duplicate value is returned as null

I have also ran a query to check the size of the array it is showing as 3 instead of 4, can someone please explain what is happening and how to fix it

Comment: Can you post your query with script ?